# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch for Matrix transpose

Tags: matlab

My motive here is to calculate parameters of a model using Least Square Estimation method.
Variable W stores the 'time' and CF stores the no. of faults occurred. I tried testing it on different Software Reliability Models (more like functions, as I've define below in 'func' variable), and only in some of them this error occurred.

```
W=xlsread(file,'A:A');
CF=xlsread(file,'B:B');
a(1)=100;
a(2)=1;
dy = CF*0.04;
func = inline('a(1).*(1-exp(-a(2).*W))','a','W'); 
Nrepeat=100;
sd = 0.3;
zfactor = 2;
outcut=10;
pList=zeros(Nrepeat,3);
for rep =1:Nrepeat
rep
[a,r,j] = nlinfit(W,CF,func,a);
%copy fit to list
pList(rep,:) = a'; <--- ERROR


ERROR : 
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
Error in lse_go (line 59)
pList(rep,:) = a';
```

I have tried using a.'; , a,' , a' but still it shows the same error. How do I remove this error?

Comment: What is the size of *a*? It should be 1x3 if you are trying to assign it to one of the rows of the 100x3 matrix.

Comment: @brodroll Well, thank you so much. I was being plain ignorant about its size. I just realized I need to change pList to (Nrepeat, n); 
I defined n=length(a);